# Merging two sorted lists

Tags: python

I want to combine two lists by using a loop that compares the data in two lists.

Here's my list:

```py
t1 = [1,3,5]
t2 = [2,4,6]
```

Here's my code so far, but this code keep showing index error:

```py
t1 = [1,3,5]
t2 = [2,4,6]

sorted_list = []

i, j = 0, 0
while t1 and t2:
    if t1[i] < t2[j]:
        sorted_list.append("t1")
        i += 1
    else:
        sorted_list.append("t2")
        j += 1


sorted_list
```

The output is supposed to look like the following:

```
['t1', 't2', 't1', 't2', 't1', 't2']
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `while t1 and t2` will always remain true, since neither `t1` nor `t2` are being changed during the loop.

Comment: Shouldn't your output be [1,2,3,4,5,6]?

Comment: Yes, but I want to change it as [1 -> 't1', 2 -> 't2', 3 -> 't1', 4 ->'t2', 5 ->'t1', 6->'t2']

Comment: That is not valid Pyton. What do you mean with that desired structure?

Comment: @trincot How's this not valid Python?

Comment: @deceze, I was replying to the comment just above mine? There is a syntax issue.

Comment: @trincot I don't think that was supposed to be valid Python.

Comment: So my comment is fine then? I am asking what they mean with it.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want this:

```
sorted_list = sorted([(i, 't1') for i in t1] + [(i, 't2') for i in t2])
sorted_list = [i[1] for i in sorted_list]
```

Explanation:

1. [Create](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) the list `[(1, 't1'), (3, 't1'), .., (2, 't2'), ..]`, which combines the values you want to end up with (`'t1'` etc.) with the values you want to sort by (`1` etc.).
2. Simply sort that list. Since the comparison values are first in the tuple, the sorting already works as desired out of the box.
3. Unpack the list to discard the sorting values.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues with your code:

1. Your `while` loop needs to terminate when all of the elements are exhausted. Since nonempty lists are truthy, your code will not terminate.
2. Before indexing into the list, you need to check whether the indices you're accessing are valid. Otherwise, you will reach the end of one of the lists, and then try to access an index past the end of the list, causing an `IndexError`.

Here is a code snippet that resolves both issues:

```py
t1 = [1,3,5]
t2 = [2,4,6]

sorted_list = []

i, j = 0, 0
while i != len(t1) or j != len(t2):
    if i != len(t1) and (j == len(t2) or t1[i] < t2[j]):
        sorted_list.append("t1")
        i += 1
    else:
        sorted_list.append("t2")
        j += 1


print(sorted_list)
```

This outputs:

```py
['t1', 't2', 't1', 't2', 't1', 't2']
```